# Pra que serve o atributo allow em iframes e como usá-lo?

Tags: html

Segundo o site do *MDN Web Docs* o atributo `allow` serve para

> Specifies a feature policy for the <iframe>.

Traduzido

> Especifica uma política de recursos para o <iframe>.

[Fonte](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe)

Essa tal [Política de Recursos](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Feature_Policy) seria para um desenvolvedor fazer determinadas coisas com os recursos e APIs do navegador, mas eu não entendi ainda para que isso serve e como funciona na prática.

**Exemplo**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/0SSYzl9fXOQ" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    
</body>
</html>
```

O exemplo acima contêm um vídeo do YouTube sendo incorporado na página através de um `iframe`. O `iframe` possui o atributo `allow` que tem os valores `accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture`, então o que vai acontecer quando esses valores forem definidos? Quais valores possíveis eu posso colocar no atributo `allow`?.

Comment: São as permissões que vão ser liberadas pelo navegador/youtube

Comment: Como assim permissões? se no atributo `allow` no exemplo que dei acima, está com o valor `autoplay` como que o navegador vai liberar essa permissão de ativar/desativar/modificar sendo que, por exemplo, o Google Chrome ignora o atributo `autoplay` e não funciona! então neste caso não seria inútil em utilizar?

Comment: O autoplay não funciona em alguns casos, tipo navegador desatualizado, sem o https, etc... Mas isso também é útil para o Youtube

Comment: Mas é nas versões antigas do Google Chrome que o `autoplay` funciona! atualmente também funciona, mas é necessário o atributo `muted` estar incluso, mas não é essa minha pergunta.

Comment: Eu acho que esse atributo serve apenas para informar à API quais os recursos disponíveis no iframe. Os valores não são padronizados (eu acho). O desenvolvedor da API que usa eles e nomeia como quiser. Por exemplo, eu poderia desenvolver uma API e usar um valor `allow="telacheia"`, onde a API verifica se a tag possui o valor `telacheia` no atributo `allow` para que o usuário possa exibir algo em tela cheia (ex., um vídeo).

Comment: @Sam é pode ser isso! na web não tem muita informação sobre esse atributo o único local que eu encontrei foi no site MDN Web Docs, mas também tem pouca informação.

Comment: Se você acha que a minha resposta não tem informações suficientes ou não responde a todas as suas dúvidas, por favor, comente para que eu possa melhorá-la

Comment: Eu só queria um exemplo na prática do uso destinado a esse atributo para poder ficar mais claro.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## TL;DR

Esse atributo pode ativar (permitir) ou desativar (não permitir) um recurso de um conteúdo de terceiros.

## Como funciona

Para entender esse atributo, temos que entender o que é a **Política de Recursos**.

A Política de recursos permite que os desenvolvedores da Web ativem, desabilitem e modifiquem o comportamento de determinados recursos e APIs no navegador. É semelhante à Política de Segurança de Conteúdo, mas controla os **recursos**, as **características** em vez do comportamento de segurança.

Em poucas palavras
a Política de Recursos fornece um mecanismo para declarar explicitamente que funcionalidade é usada (ou não usada) em todo o site. Isso permite que você bloqueie as práticas recomendadas pelo conteúdo, mesmo que a base de código dele evolua com o tempo, assim é possível compor conteúdo de terceiros com mais segurança limitando quais recursos estão disponíveis.

Com a Política de recursos, você aceita um conjunto de "políticas" para o navegador aplicar em recursos específicos usados ​​em um site. Essas políticas restringem quais APIs o site pode acessar ou modificar o comportamento padrão do navegador para determinados recursos.

Exemplos do que você pode fazer com a Política de Recursos:

- Altere o comportamento padrão da reprodução automática em vídeos para celular e de terceiros.
- Restrinja um site a usar APIs sensíveis, como câmera ou microfone.
- Permita que iframes usem a API em tela cheia.
- Bloqueie o uso de APIs desatualizadas, como XHR síncrono.
- Verifique se as imagens estão dimensionadas corretamente e não são muito grandes para a viewport.

## Conceitos e uso

A Política de recursos permite controlar quais origens podem usar quais recursos, na página de nível superior e nos quadros incorporados. Essencialmente, você escreve uma política, que é uma lista de origens permitidas para cada recurso. Para todos os recursos controlados pela Política de recursos, o recurso só será ativado no documento ou quadro atual se sua origem corresponder à lista de origens permitidas.

Para cada recurso controlado por política, o navegador mantém uma lista de origens para as quais o recurso está ativado, conhecido como lista de permissões. Se você não especificar uma política para um recurso, uma lista de permissões padrão será usada. A lista de permissões padrão é específica para cada recurso.

## Escrevendo uma política

Uma política é descrita usando um conjunto de diretivas de política individuais. Uma diretiva de política é uma combinação de um nome de recurso definido e uma lista de permissões de origens que podem usar o recurso.

### Especificando sua política:

Política de recursos fornece duas maneiras de especificar políticas para controlar os recursos:

- O [cabeçalho HTTP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Feature-Policy) da política de recursos.
- O atributo de permissão `allow` em `iframe`s.

A principal diferença entre o cabeçalho HTTP e o atributo `allow` é que o atributo `allow` controla apenas os recursos em um `iframe`. O cabeçalho controla os recursos da resposta e qualquer conteúdo incorporado na página.

Um exemplo simples é este:

```
<iframe allow="camera 'none'; microphone 'none'">
```

O atributo `allow` bloqueia o conteúdo do `iframe` de usar a câmera e o microfone do usuário.

Para mais detalhes, veja [Usando a Política de Recursos](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Feature_Policy/Using_Feature_Policy).

## Tipos de recursos controlados por políticas

Embora a Política de Recursos forneça controle de vários recursos usando uma sintaxe consistente, o comportamento dos recursos controlados por políticas varia e depende de vários fatores.

O princípio geral é que deve haver uma maneira intuitiva ou ininterrupta para que os desenvolvedores da Web detectem ou manejem o caso quando o recurso estiver desativado. Recursos recém-introduzidos podem ter uma API explícita para sinalizar o estado. Os recursos existentes que mais tarde se integram à Política de Recursos normalmente usam mecanismos existentes. Algumas abordagens incluem:

- Retorne `false` para APIs JavaScript que exigem permissões de usuário.
- Retorne `false` ou um erro de uma API JavaScript existente que fornece acesso ao recurso.
- Altere os valores ou opções padrão que controlam o comportamento do recurso.

O conjunto atual de recursos controlados por políticas se enquadra em duas grandes categorias:

- Aplicação de boas práticas para boas experiências do usuário.
- Fornecendo controle granular sobre recursos sensíveis ou poderosos.

## Práticas recomendadas para boas experiências do usuário

Existem vários recursos controlados por políticas para ajudar a aplicar as práticas recomendadas para fornecer bom desempenho e experiências do usuário.

Na maioria dos casos, os recursos controlados por política representam funcionalidades que, quando usadas, afetam negativamente a experiência do usuário. Para evitar a quebra de conteúdo da Web existente, o padrão para esses recursos controlados por política é permitir que a funcionalidade seja usada por todas as origens. As práticas recomendadas são aplicadas usando políticas que desabilitam os recursos controlados por políticas.

Os recursos incluem:

- Animações indutoras de layout
- Formatos de imagem herdados
- Imagens de grandes dimensões
- Scripts síncronos
- `XMLHTTPRequest` síncrono
- Imagens não otimizadas
- Mídia não dimensionada
- Controle granular sobre certos recursos

A web fornece funcionalidades e APIs que podem ter riscos de privacidade ou segurança se abusadas. Em alguns casos, convém limitar estritamente como essa funcionalidade é usada em um site. Existem recursos controlados por políticas que permitem ativar / desativar a funcionalidade para origens ou quadros específicos em um site. Onde disponível, o recurso se integra à API de Permissões ou mecanismos específicos do recurso para verificar se o recurso está disponível.

Os recursos incluem (mais detalhes em [lista de recursos](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Feature-Policy#Directives)):

- Acelerômetro
- Sensor de luz ambiente
- Reprodução automática
- Câmera
- Mídia criptografada
- Tela cheia
- Geolocalização
- Giroscópio
- Magnetômetro
- Microfone
- Midi
- Pedido de Pagamento
- Imagem em imagem
- Alto falante
- USB
- VR / XR

## Inferindo a política

Os scripts podem consultar informações sobre a política de recursos por meio do objeto [`FeaturePolicy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FeaturePolicy) localizado em [`Document.featurePolicy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/featurePolicy) ou [`HTMLIFrameElement.featurePolicy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLIFrameElement/featurePolicy).

Veja algumas [demonstrações](http://feature-policy-demos.appspot.com/) de várias políticas